# Variadic expander without a typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

One trick often used to perform a variadic parameter expansion is using an un-sized array typedef in combination with the comma operator, like below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
void expander(Ts&&... ts)
{
    using expand = int[];
    (void)expand{0, (std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), 0)...};
}
void f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    expander(f, f);
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4131fd862e185ef)

**Can we do this without introducing a typedef?** If I try directly

```
(void)int[]{0, (std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), 0)...};
```

gcc/clang spit out

> error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

and if I try to parenthesize, the code compiles but I believe it is non-standard compliant:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-Wpedantic]

Comment: Use `std::initializer_list<char>`, if you really hate the typedef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this expression

```
(void)int[]{0, (std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), 0)...};
```

you're trying to use a functional notation cast to create a temporary array. That won't work because the language only allows the functional notation to be used with either a *simple-type-specifier* or a *typename-specifier*.

From [*[expr.type.conv]/3*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#3)

> Similarly, a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a *braced-init-list* creates a temporary object of the specified type direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified *braced-init-list*, and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

And if you go lookup the definition of *simple-type-specifier* under [*[dcl.type.simple]*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1), it doesn't include anything with array brackets. In fact, it doesn't even include anything that's more than one word. This is why writing `int(1)` is valid, but `signed int(1)` isn't.

So, with C++11/14 you need a `typedef` or declare an array variable. But, with a C++1z compiler, you can make use of fold expressions and avoid both

```
template<typename... Ts>
void expander(Ts&&... ts)
{
    (void(std::forward<Ts>(ts)()), ...);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ba1369ac6cb93fa)

Answer (score 5):

> Can we do this without introducing a typedef?

Without a typedef, but with a variable

```
template<typename... Ts>
void expander(Ts&&... ts)
{
    int dummy[] = {0, (std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), void(), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why the second `void()` after `std::forward`?

Comment: @vsoftco Because responsible C++ programmers use protection ... against overloaded comma operators :)

Comment: @Praetorian Ohhhh yes, sure, forgot about that ;)

Comment: @Praetorian But then shouldn't the `void` be before `std::forward`? Because the function can return some object which overloads `operator,(MyType, void(&)())`.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, you can cast the return value of the callable, or you can do what Jarod does. `void()` is not a function type, it's an expression of type `void`, and you cannot overload the comma operator with `void`.

Comment: why do we need `(void)`  before `dummy`?

Comment: @IvanKush: To avoid warning (in most compilers) for unused variable.

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 you'll could do it with folds as:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void expander(Ts&&... ts) {
    (..., std::forward<Ts>(ts)());
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/maB8yFGAn7QrRANc)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts>
void expander(Ts&&... ts)
{
    int dummy[sizeof...(Ts)] = {(std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), 0)...};
}
void f()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    expander(f, f, f);
    expander();
}
```

https://ideone.com/BzNXhD

Comment: Actually this is really interesting, upvoted. Why cannot I just use `int dummy[] = {(std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), 0)...};`? The code in this case doesn't compile.

Comment: @vsoftco This is practically the same as Jarod's answer, but it doesn't handle all cases like his answer does, and has the added unnecessary verbosity of specifying an array size. The call with no arguments defines an array of size 0, it's allowed by gcc and clang as an extension (ideone hides warnings if the code compiles). If you want to do this right, the code needs to be `int dummy[sizeof...(Ts) + 1] = {0, (std::forward<Ts>(ts)(), 0)...};`, but there's no need for array size in the first place.